# Question about epinephrine

Tags: physiology, endocrinology

In my class we were told that adrenaline (or epinephrine) causes vasoconstriction.
My question was I had always thought that people took this via an EpiPen when they were having an allergic reaction.

So I thought it would make sense, that it would dilate vessels, because this will allow more air through. Or does the constriction help because it tightens the vessels in the throat allowing a reduction of swelling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An allergic reaction requiring an epipen can be caused by swelling in the throat and/or bronchoconstriction (spasms decreasing the diameter of bronchioles). Bronchoconstriction can occur in the absence of soft tissue swelling in the lips, tongue and throat, and vs. versa.

Epinephrine reduces pharyngeal edema (swelling) because it is a potent vasoconstrictor in small arterioles and precapillary sphincters in most body organ systems. This is effected through alpha-1 adrenergic receptor activation. While the blood pressure and heart rate increase (due to beta-1 adrenergic effects), the permeability at the capillary level is decreased, relieving swelling.

At the same time, epinephrine relaxes bronchial muscle. It has a powerful bronchodilator action when bronchial muscle is contracted because it is a powerful beta2 adrenergic agonist.

Finally, epinephrine inhibits antigen-induced release of inflammatory mediators from mast cells, and to a lesser extent from diminution of bronchial secretions and congestion within the mucosa. Inhibition of mast cell secretion is mediated by beta2 adrenergic receptors.

[image]

<sup>Adapted from Simons. Kemp et al. World Allergy Organization Journal 2008 1(Suppl 2):S18-S26   doi:10.1186/1939-4551-1-S2-S18</sup>

<sub>[Epinephrine: The Drug of Choice for Anaphylaxis--A Statement of the World Allergy Organization](http://www.waojournal.org/content/1/S2/S18/#B39)</sub>